# MySql - Is tables name swap is an atomic operation

Tags: mysql, triggers, atomic

I have a table, let's call it `myTbl`.
I also have two tables - `Monitor` and `Monitor_bkp`.
now i built a Trigger to create a new row in Monitor whenever the is an update in `myTbl`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mon_task_after_update_task 
AFTER UPDATE ON myTbl
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO Monitor VALUES(new.id, SYSDATE())
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_modified=SYSDATE();
```

all works good, and i have a lot of updates to `myTbl` at all time.
now my question is if i'll swap the names of `Monitor` and `Monitor_bkp`, using

```
RENAME TABLE foo TO foo_old, foo_new To foo;
```

Is there a possibility the trigger will fire while the swap is going and if so will it fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-table.html) (and my experience using this feature for log rotation) the operation is atomic and the threads that are trying to use the table have to wait for `RENAME TABLE` to complete.

This also means that `RENAME TABLE` will wait for all transactions which touched the tables to finish, and while waiting it will lock every subsequent transaction which tries to touch the tables.

Basically everything will freeze for the duration of the longest transaction during the swap, but will be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

As Vatev already mentioned, the trigger will not fire.

If you still feel anxious about it (or for any other uses) you may want to add a user-defined variable (e.g. `@ALLOW_TRIGGER`) into your program logic and check its value inside the trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
myTrigger: BEGIN
    IF (@ALLOW_TRIGGER = FALSE)
    THEN
        LEAVE myTrigger
    END;

    # rest of trigger logic

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Tnx for the answer, but i`m trying to keep the trigger to a minimum, a lesson learned from privous fails